# What to do with abandoned questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

There are some questions that keep getting bumped by the Community-bot although they seem to be abandoned by the original poster ([example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7228/bitmap-font-rendering-uv-generation-and-vertex-placement)).

How to deal with these? What happens to questions that are asked by somebody who then never comes back (because he found an answer elswhere)? Will the bot bump them to infinity or will he "give up" when the question remains unanswered?

Comment: So the short answer is: 5k+ rep users can vote to close questions.

Comment: Just because the OP isn't around any longer (and thus will never accept an answer) doesn't mean the question should be closed though (even though this specific example should have been).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few random, relatively highly viewed **UNANSWERED** questions will be bumped every hour.

For our definition of unanswered, see here:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

If you think any of the answers are decent, the thing to do is upvote them -- or of course edit, comment, flag for removal, provide your own answer, etcetera.

Comment: Ok, so questions that aren't closed/deleted by admins and don't have an accepted answer will get bumped. There's no "bump-limit" to a question?

Comment: has nothing to do with accepted answer; did you read the blog entry?

Comment: The problem with this specific question is that there's no possible good answer and it should've been closed...

Comment: @Jeff: I read the blog entry, but my comment was poorly worded, sorry. I meant accepted in the sense described in the blog. I was just wondering if the bot will bump a question forever as long as it remains "unanswered".

Comment: @joe sure, close it as "too localized" -- that's a valid outcome as well.

Comment: Well, I did last time it came up - but now it didn't show up as "close (1)" and I couldn't close it again. How long are votes-to-close valid?

Comment: @joe it depends; we changed some stuff about that in July: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581 you can always flag for mod attention.

Comment: @Jeff: It would be nice if, when it comes back up, I could re-vote to close. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/ for example could probably garner enough close votes if enough >5k rep people saw it at the same time, but now the votes have expired and people who have already voted cannot revote.